# Why Racket treats differently mutation on REPL and mutation using both the definition window and the REPL?

Tags: racket, read-eval-print-loop, mutation

Usually, I avoid using mutations since you rarely need them.

However, I need them and I am trying to understand better somethings. There is a specific behavior that intrigues me and I would like to ask for your help to understand it better.

If I type on the REPL the change bellow everything works:

```
> (define x 1)
> (set! x (+ x 1))
> x
2
```

If I put the assignment and the mutation on the definition window it also works:

```
(define y 1)
y
(set! y (+ y 1))
y
```

After running the file, I can see on the REPL the following correct result:

```
1
2
>
```

However, if I put the definition of variable `x` on the definition windows and if I try to set! it to a new value on the REPL I get an error:

```
; Definition Window

(define y 1)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; REPL

> (set! y (+ y 1))
. . y: cannot modify a constant
```

Why does that happen?
Shouldn't interactive programming be used especially for situations like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe see [here](https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-October/064625.html) (I don't know racket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  [Matthias Felleisen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthias_Felleisen), one of the main responsible for the development of Racket so far:

> The DrRacket REPL allows set!s on those variables that are assignable in the module and no others. That's by design. Roughly speaking, think of the Definitions window as a module and the REPL a way to perform computations as if we were a client of the module that can also use all of its internally defined functions, think super-client. But this super-client view does not enable you to mutate variables that weren't mutable in the first place .. just like a client can't do that either.

This information was presented in [Racket's Mail list](https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-October/064625.html) 7 years ago as pointed out in a comment of my own question in the post above.